# Typescript JSX with Generics - Parameter implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

When using JSX syntax with Generics, Typescript is able to infer properties normally, except the type of function parameters.

Example code:

```js
interface Dictionary {
  a: JSX.IntrinsicElements['a'];
  button: JSX.IntrinsicElements['button'];
}

type Props<T extends 'a' | 'button'> = Dictionary[T] & {
  as: T;
};

function Test<T extends 'a' | 'button'>(args: Props<T>) {
  return null;
}

<Test as="a" href="#" onClick={(arg) => {}} />; // Parameter 'arg' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Test({
  as: 'a',
  href: '#',
  onClick: (arg) => {}, // No error
});
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgBFgNgJqUoBPOAN7k4cFAC44AKQDKADQB0ASVpQaAZ3YBRADZIQSWmoDa%20FPgC6FEQCMArjBhcJMhcpirqGtDr0GYx-DsHLgsKAF9KGF4wZgAFHDA1AB4AFTgkAA86agATNQIzOAAfAiDHanwAPjgAXlZ2GE5uPiMU8zgAMkFhUTUJFPCKckxbag4uOBSkNRhU9KyDPIL8YtL7cqqACh4Acz64eIhE1MqASm6RIhhbKGo4alttbXDKVOn4FDUagCIUb7gABZETA-ADE-y4AGFtOwANY1ATbKA7c41aoCMJhOAAekqQymM02QhEnwkpnwABoekCkJgyaDKT0oTC0LCJEiUbV0WEqWFThQgA)

If I place the mouse over the onClick property, it can tell the type of the onClick (React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLAnchorElement>), but still cannot infer the parameter's type.

Comment: Looks like a TS bug, see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44596 .

Comment: It works as expected if you provide explicit generic parameter: `<Test<'a'> as="a" href="#" onClick={(e) => { }} />;`.

Comment: @captain-yossarian I'm thinking it might be the same as https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44596 and in any case the OP has apparently already done this at https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46961, so ‍♂️.

Comment: @jcalz you are right, it looks like  duplicate for me either.

Comment: @jcalz I admire your ability of searching typescript issues. I was trying to find related issue but without success :D

Answer (score 0):

Just explicitly define it as any with `args: any` and it should stop showing it as error :)